# Javascript Notification function but no output text

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I wrote a notification function for my Vue app and I import it in my store(Vuex).

```js
export default function getNotificationText(notification) {
  // Parent types.
  const DRIVE = 'drv'
  const DRIVE_GALLERY = 'dgl'
  const EXPERIENCE = 'exp'
  const EXPERIENCE_GALLERY = 'egl'
  const STAY = 'sty'
  const STAY_GALLERY = 'sgl'
  const LOCATION_PHOTO = 'lpt'
  const DRIVE_PHOTO = 'dpt'
  const EXPERIENCE_PHOTO = 'ept'
  const STAY_PHOTO = 'spt'
  const LOCATION_REVIEW = 'lrv'
  const DRIVE_REVIEW = 'drv'
  const EXPERIENCE_REVIEW = 'erv'
  const STAY_REVIEW = 'srv'
  const LOCATION_QUESTION = 'lqt'
  const DRIVE_QUESTION = 'dqt'
  const EXPERIENCE_QUESTION = 'eqt'
  const STAY_QUESTION = 'sqt'
  const TRIP = 'trp'
  const TRIP_PHOTO = 'tpt'
  const DRIVE_GALLERY_COMMENT = 'dgc'
  const EXPERIENCE_GALLERY_COMMENT = 'egc'
  const STAY_GALLERY_COMMENT = 'sgc'
  const LOCATION_PHOTO_COMMENT = 'lpc'
  const DRIVE_PHOTO_COMMENT = 'dpc'
  const EXPERIENCE_PHOTO_COMMENT = 'epc'
  const STAY_PHOTO_COMMENT = 'spc'
  const LOCATION_REVIEW_COMMENT = 'lrc'
  const DRIVE_REVIEW_COMMENT = 'drc'
  const EXPERIENCE_REVIEW_COMMENT = 'erc'
  const STAY_REVIEW_COMMENT = 'src'
  const LOCATION_QUESTION_COMMENT = 'lqc'
  const DRIVE_QUESTION_COMMENT = 'dqc'
  const EXPERIENCE_QUESTION_COMMENT = 'eqc'
  const STAY_QUESTION_COMMENT = 'sqc'
  const TRIP_COMMENT = 'trc'
  const TRIP_PHOTO_COMMENT = 'tpc'
  const USER = 'usr'
  const notificationText = ''
  // Build user text.
  const userText = notification.sender.first_name + ' ' + notification.sender.last_name
  // Build action text.
  const action = notification.action
  const actionText = ''
  // actions started
  const COMMENT = 'cmt'
  const LOVE = 'lov'
  const FOLLOW = 'flw'
  const ACCEPT_BOOKING = 'apb'
  const ADD_PHOTO = 'adp'
  const ADD_REVIEW = 'adr'
  const ADD_QUESTION = 'adq'
  if (action == COMMENT) {
    const actionText = 'commented on your'
  } else if (action === LOVE) {
    const actionText = 'liked your'
  } else if (action === FOLLOW) {
    const actionText = 'started following you'
  } else if (action === ACCEPT_BOOKING) {
    const actionText = 'accepted your booking'
  } else if (action === ADD_PHOTO) {
    const actionText = 'added a new photo on your'
  } else if (action === ADD_REVIEW) {
    const actionText = 'added a new review on your '
  } else if (action === ADD_QUESTION) {
    const actionText = 'asked a new question on your'
  }
  // Build parent text.
  const parentType = notification.parent.type
  const parentText = ''
  if (action === ADD_PHOTO || action === ADD_REVIEW || action === ADD_QUESTION) {
    if (parentType === DRIVE_PHOTO || parentType === DRIVE_REVIEW || parentType === DRIVE_QUESTION) {
      const parentText = 'drive'
    } else if (parentType === EXPERIENCE_PHOTO || parentType === EXPERIENCE_REVIEW || parentType === EXPERIENCE_QUESTION) {
      const parentText = 'experience'
    } else if (parentType === STAY_PHOTO || parentType === STAY_REVIEW || parentType === STAY_QUESTION) {
      const parentText = 'stay'
    }
  } else if (action === COMMENT || action === LOVE) {
    if (parentType === DRIVE_GALLERY || parentType === EXPERIENCE_GALLERY || parentType === STAY_GALLERY || parentType === LOCATION_PHOTO || parentType === DRIVE_PHOTO || parentType === EXPERIENCE_PHOTO || parentType === STAY_PHOTO || parentType === TRIP_PHOTO) {
      const parentText = 'photo'
    } else if (parentType === LOCATION_REVIEW || parentType === DRIVE_REVIEW || parentType === EXPERIENCE_REVIEW || parentType === STAY_REVIEW) {
      const parentText = 'review'
    } else if (parentType === LOCATION_QUESTION || parentType === DRIVE_QUESTION || parentType === EXPERIENCE_QUESTION || parentType === STAY_QUESTION) {
      const parentText = 'question'
    } else if (parentType === TRIP) {
      const parentText = 'trip'
    } else if (['DRIVE_GALLERY_COMMENT', 'EXPERIENCE_GALLERY_COMMENT', 'STAY_GALLERY_COMMENT', 'LOCATION_PHOTO_COMMENT', 'DRIVE_PHOTO_COMMENT', 'EXPERIENCE_PHOTO_COMMENT', 'STAY_PHOTO_COMMENT', 'LOCATION_REVIEW_COMMENT', 'DRIVE_REVIEW_COMMENT', 'EXPERIENCE_REVIEW_COMMENT', 'STAY_REVIEW_COMMENT', 'LOCATION_QUESTION_COMMENT', 'DRIVE_QUESTION_COMMENT', 'EXPERIENCE_QUESTION_COMMENT', 'STAY_QUESTION_COMMENT', 'TRIP_COMMENT', 'TRIP_PHOTO_COMMENT'].indexOf(parentType) > -1) {
      const parentText = 'comment'
      console.log(parentText)
    }
  }
  // Combine texts.
  const outputText = userText + ' ' + actionText
  if (parentText) {
    const outputText = parentText
  }
  // Return output text.
  return outputText
}
```

I want to show the output text according to the if conditions `userText` is already defined as user `firstname` and `lastname` but I didn't get ActionText or ParentText. The inside of the if statement is working fine and I can get `console.log` but outside of the if statement it's not working. Please help me.

Here is the Pastebin link for the code: https://pastebin.com/n0TaXxcJ

Comment: `const` means that you declare a variable that won't be changed in his scope. In your code, you declare the same variable lots of times. You can use `let`.

Comment: @AlonShmiel i fixed it with changin const to let,  let actionText = '' , let parentText = '' andremoved const from if conditions it works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Combine texts.
let outputText = userText + ' ' + actionText
if (parentText) {
  outputText = outputText + parentText
}

return outputText
```

You are overriding `outputText` in the end. Also, you defined it as another variable, use let instead.

Also, it's better to use packages like [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) instead of copy/pasting `const DRIVE = 'drv'` and others everywhere. You have to make changes eveyrwhere if you decide to change something otherwise.

---

Edit:

You can replace that

```
// Combine texts.
const outputText = userText + ' ' + actionText
if (parentText) {
  const outputText = parentText
}
// Return output text.
return outputText
```

block with `return userText + ' ' + actionText + ' ' + parentText` and get the same effect. If parentText is empty, nothing will be added, right?

Comment: Thanks for the help just fixed with ' let ' instead of ' const ' to all

Comment: Thank you all guys for the awesome help and awesome community this problem is solved but the correct answer or the idea given by Alon Shmie and Aravind Voggu helped me too for now i cant set Alon Shmie answer as accpted beacuse there is no option to set like that , so setting this question is resolved..